# How to post a form in Adobe CQ 5.5?

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I am very new to CQ, I have been strugglung with this for a very long time now. What I want to do is "Create a page That accepts username password using regular  tag and post the data to a servlet.

The servlet checks username password using str.equals("username") hardcoded and redirects to another page i.e. success or failure"
Please note that I am building a website that will has common users like for example 'People who are registered to a site like stackoverflow etc' These users are **not authors** who can edit content.
A very basic task but too difficult for me. Here is the code.
I wrote sling Post servlet using CRXDE created bundle sucessfully

```
package com.example;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
@Component(immediate=true, metatype=false, label="EXAMPLE SERVLET")
@Service
@Properties(value = {   
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name="sling.servlet.methods", value={"POST"}),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name="sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value={"sling/servlet/default"}),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name="sling.servlet.selectors", value={"SELECTORNAME"}),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name="sling.servlet.extensions", value={"html"})
})
public class ExampleServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleServlet.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //String redirect = request.getParameter(":redirect");

        log.info("The Sling Post Servlet- Example Servlet has been called !! ");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(username.equals("oliver")&& password.equals("oliver"))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/content/mywebsite/en/products");
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/content/mywebsite/en/services");
        }
        log.info("Sucessfull Response Sent ");
    }

} 

I get error as 
Status  
200
Message 
OK
Location    /example.SELECTORNAME.html
Parent Location /
Path    
/example.SELECTORNAME.html
Referer http://localhost:4502/content/mywebsite/en/products.html
ChangeLog   
<pre>modified("/example.SELECTORNAME.html/username");<br/
```

> 

and the jsp is as follows

```
<%--

  My Content Page Componenet component.

  General Description

--%><%
%><%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" %>

<%
%><%
    // TODO add you code here
%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<cq:include script="head.jsp"/>



<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>My First Page </div>
<form action="/example.SELECTORNAME.html" method="POST">
<input type="text" name ="username"/>
<input type="password" name "password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>

</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: could you check in the osgi component list if your servlet is active? (/system/console/components). It seems the regular POST servlet is taking care of the request

Comment: The ExampleServlet is Active.... I checked it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet path is missing in your file. 
/**
 * @scr.component metatype="false"
 * @scr.service interface="javax.servlet.Servlet"
 * @scr.property name="sling.servlet.paths" values="/bin/login"
 */
public class LoginServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
......
}

jsp -

form name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" method="post" action="/bin/login"

Comment: True path was missing and I replaced all complex ananotations with @SlingServlet Just refer here 
http://blogs.adobe.com/aaa/2012/09/cq-tips-and-tricks-1-how-to-define-a-slingservlet-cq5-5-5-6.html <-- This says it all !!